# segfault with if statement

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this code here in C,

When that else statement is there, and i try to print the pointer reference, i get a seg fault. printing the pointer reference in the if(videoPlaying) portion, prints fine, but anywhere outside that, it segfaults.

omxPlayer is defined as FILE *omxPlayer = NULL;

```
if(videoPlaying == 0)
{
    omxPlayer = popen("omxplayer diehard.mp4", "w");
    printf("%p\n", omxPlayer);
    videoPlaying = 1;
}
else
{
    printf("%p\n", omxPlayer);
}
```

Comment: no, its defined at the top of main as FILE *omxPlayer = NULL;

Comment: I think you have other problems with the stuff you are doing when video is playing. Printing a pointer value should never cause segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the control flow of your code when `videoPlaying != 0` , Most likely You are corrupting memory somewhere in that flow. Just printing out the address of an corrupted pointer should still work fine since it the address is always valid only contents in that address are invalid, so certainly there is something more that is wrong and not seen in the code that you show.

Your best option is to review the code or run your code under **valgrind** or any such memory analysis tool and it should point you out what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, valgrind was very helpful. It was related to another pointer further up in the code.